# Problem with Awodey's Category Theory Exercise 8.11, showing Sets/X is cartesian closed using a specific hint.

Tags: category-theory, slice-category

> 11. Show that every slice category $\mathbb{Sets}/X$ is cartesian closed. Calculate the
>     exponential of two objects $A \to X$ and $B \to X$ by first determining the
>     Yoneda embedding $y : X \to \mathbb{Sets}/X$ , and then applying the formula for
>     exponentials of presheaves. Finally, observe that $\mathbb{Sets}/X$ is a topos, and
>     determine its subobject classifier.

I feel like using the equivalence relation between $\mathbb{Sets}/X$ and $\mathbb{Sets}^{X}$, but I'm curious about the hint given, regarding $y: X \to \mathbb{Sets}/X$, since the set $X$ contains no non-identity arrows when regarded as a category. How is this related to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The hint is fine. The fact that $X$ has only identity arrows makes things very easy to calculate.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you help me a bit more? I have no idea how should I use the embedding with the arrows $A \to X$.

Comment: You are supposed to use the equivalence between $\textbf{Set}_{/ X}$ and $\textbf{Set}^X$ to apply the hint. You have seen how to calculate exponentials in categories of presheaves, haven't you?

Comment: @ZhenLin Thanks, I got it!